# javascript BigInt multiplication gives wrong result

Tags: javascript

Today I have tried to multiply large numbers using javascript BigInt, I noticed It is producing the wrong result. I tried to find the max size of the BigInt but the websites I have checked not mentioned about the max size of BigInt. Instead, the documentation says BigInt can have arbitrary length.

```
(BigInt(9493965694520825) * BigInt(9493965694520825)).toString()
```

Above multiplication produced `90135384608738272013494969638976` but the expected value is `90135384608738291001426358680625`. Am I missing anything?

Some websites I have checked to find the max value of BigInt:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt

https://javascript.info/bigint

https://v8.dev/features/bigint

Comment: `9493965694520825` is too large a number, use a string: `(BigInt('9493965694520825') * BigInt('9493965694520825')).toString()`

Comment: [Related](//google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+js+bigint+is+not+precise): [BigInt issue of javascript](/q/56696469/4642212).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that the numbers already get rounded before you pass them to the BigInt constructor - the literal 9493965694520825 will evaluate to 9493965694520824, and that's what will then get converted to a BigInt. To create BigInts of that size correctly, just use a BigInt literal instead of the constructor:

```
(9493965694520825n*9493965694520825n).toString()
```

That will yield the correct value of 90135384608738291001426358680625 then instead.

Comment: Ahh, got it. My bad :)